# Find a match for query within text

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, data-structures

This question was asked recently during interview and i couldn't solve so need some suggestion how can i solve the problem

Declaration: I can not use REGEX or any in-built libraries

***** Problem Statement is as below*********

**matches
Input: text (string), query (string)
Output: true if you can find a match for query within text, false otherwise
If there are no special characters, most languages have a contains method that will just do this.
One special character: '?' -- if you find '?' in the query string, it signals that the previous character is optional (matches 0 or 1 times).

Examples:

- No question marks:
- matches("hello World", "hello") returns true

  - matches("hello World", "world") returns false
  - matches("hello World", "o W")returns true
  - matches("hello World", "W o") returns false
  - matches("hello World", "h W") returns false
  - With question marks -- "l?" means "optional l":
  - matches("heo World", "hel?o") returns true
  - matches("helo World", "hel?o") returns true
    matches("hello World", "hel?o") returns false
  - Make sure you understand this case:
  - matches("hello World", "hell?lo") returns true
  - You can have more than one question mark:
  - matches("hello World", "ex?llo Worlds?") returns true

***** My approach was as below*********

```
public class StringPatternMatch
{
    public static bool MatchPattern(string inputText, string pattern)
    {
        int count = 0; int patternIndex = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < inputText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (patternIndex > pattern.Length)
                break;

            if (inputText[i] == pattern[patternIndex] ||
                (inputText[i] != pattern[patternIndex] && pattern[patternIndex + 1] == '?'))
                count++;

            patternIndex++;
        }

        return pattern.Length == count;
    }
}
```

traverse both strings from one side to other side (say from rightmost character to leftmost). If we find a matching character, we move ahead in both strings with increasing counter for pattern - at the end match count with pattern-length

Also i have provided my code but that doesn't cover all the cases

Of course i didn't go next round, but i am still thinking about this problem and haven't found accurate solution - hope to see some interesting answers!

Comment: the big thing you missed is that the pattern can start at any point in the input string.  Try to fix your code so that it returns the correct answers for the examples?  you'll learn a lot more if you spend your time trying to master the algorithm than looking around for solutions.

Comment: `matches("hello World", "o C") returns true` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 my bad, I had a typo in question - I have corrected it!

Comment: That can be done with [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) so simply it isn't worth mentioning if you know DCGs. You did not give a programming langue and you did not say if a list can be considered an array.  e.g `"hel",("l";[]),"o".`  `;` is an `or` operator, `,` is and 'and' operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea can work but your implementation is over-simplified:

```
// assumes the pattern is valid, e.g. no ??
public static boolean matches(String string, String pattern) {
    int p = 0; // position in pattern
    // because we only return boolean we can discard all optional characters at the beginning of the pattern
    while (p + 1 < pattern.length() && pattern.charAt(p + 1) == '?')
        p += 2;
    if (p >= pattern.length())
        return true;
    for (int s = 0; s < string.length(); s++) // s is position in string
        // find a valid start position for the first mandatory character in pattern and check if it matches
        if (string.charAt(s) == pattern.charAt(p) && matches(string, pattern, s + 1, p + 1))
            return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean matches(String string, String pattern, int s, int p) {
    if (p >= pattern.length()) // end of pattern reached
        return true;
    if (s >= string.length() || string.charAt(s) != pattern.charAt(p)) // end of string or no match
        // if the next character of the pattern is optional check if the rest matches
        return p + 1 < pattern.length() && pattern.charAt(p + 1) == '?' && matches(string, pattern, s, p + 2);
    // here we know the characters are matching
    if (p + 1 < pattern.length() && pattern.charAt(p + 1) == '?') // if it is an optional character
        // check if matching the optional character or skipping it leads to success
        return matches(string, pattern, s + 1, p + 2) || matches(string, pattern, s, p + 2);
    // the character wasn't optional (but matched as we know from above)
    return matches(string, pattern, s + 1, p + 1);
}
```

Comment: Looks like time complexity of this will be O(N^2)

Comment: @vran I think for real life example the performance is pretty good, but big O can be worse. E.g. `lllllll` and `ll?l?a`. You could try to match the mandatory characters first and then you try to fill up the gaps with the optional characters in-between them.